# Installation is not working on my pc

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

Currently, I have windows 7 and I need to change as ubuntu 16.04. I made a usb bootable device on my pen drive. I am installing ubuntu os so rufus is working fine but now the problem is

```
Your installation cd-rom couldn't mounted. This probably means that the cd-rom was not in the drive. If so you can insert it and try again.
```

I'm in stuck fr installation

please help me what should I do ?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't get a successful bootable pendrive. Try that step again, come back with how you did that if it didn't work. The common error is to just copy the ,iso file to the drive in the 'normal' fashion?

Comment: What program or process did you use for creating the pen drive from the iso?

Comment: Make a proper Bootable USB from Windows using a program called [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: @AlanJameson  I edited please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

When the message comes up, remove the USB and insert it again. Wait for some time and press `<Yes>`.

And If that doesn't work, Again burn the ISO to USB using Rufus, But this time select the **DD Image** mode below **format options**.

[image]

Comment: now the actual problem is partioning windows with ubuntu. and I want to uninstall windows how should it possible ?

Comment: Please if this answer helped you to boot to Ubuntu, mark this as solved. For partitioning I suggest to make a new question. Are you sure you want to remove your Windows partition? It will delete all your important files.

Comment: not having any important file in windows

Comment: I will tell you step by step

Comment: To replace windows select **Windows 7 with Ubuntu** option under **Installation Type**.